# Parallel.For in a List, acting upon the items in sequential order, only in the start

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.for, concurrent-queue

I have a `List<TaskClass> TaskList` items that we can iterate over using a Parallel loop.

The items in the list are sorted in a particular order as the TaskClass implements IComparable with its own `CompareTo(object obj)` method.
Thus we need the items acted upon in sequential order.

*Note they do NOT have to complete in sequential order, just start in sequential.*

Thus TaskList[0] should be started first; then TaskList[1], TaskList[2], ...
However, we don't care if TaskList[2] completes first, or TaskList[0].

This is the quick code I've come up with to try and alleviate this:

```
//Construct a ConcurrentQueue and populate it with our SORTED list
//of TaskClass items so when we go through a parallel loop
//they are acted upon in sorted order. A parallel loop does not
//guarantee ordering, which we need to make sure tasks with a higher
//number are done first.
ConcurrentQueue<TaskClass> cq = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskClass>();
for (int x = 0; x < TaskList.Count; x++)
    cq.Enqueue(TaskList[x]);

Parallel.For(
    0,
    cq.Count,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DISystem.MaxConcurrentThreads },
    x =>
    {
        TaskClass tc = null;
        if (cq.TryDequeue(out tc))
        {
            TaskTypeManager ttm = new TaskTypeManager();
            tc.Working = true;
            tc.Started = DateTime.Now;
            ttm.ProcessTaskItem(tc);
        }
    }
);
```

Now the issue I believe is when the Parallel.For loop completes, the original `List<TaskClass> TaskList` will not have been updated with the latest values.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

With modified code like the following? (lines marked with "//new")

```
ConcurrentQueue<TaskClass> cq = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskClass>();
for (int x = 0; x < TaskList.Count; x++)
    cq.Enqueue(TaskList[x]);

List<TaskClass> NewTaskList = new List<TaskClass>(); //new
object lockObject = new Object(); //new

Parallel.For(
    0,
    cq.Count,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DISystem.MaxConcurrentThreads },
    x =>
    {
        TaskClass tc = null;
        if (cq.TryDequeue(out tc))
        {
            TaskTypeManager ttm = new TaskTypeManager();
            tc.Working = true;
            tc.Started = DateTime.Now;
            ttm.ProcessTaskItem(tc);
            lock (lockObject) //new
            {
                NewTaskList.Add(tc);
            }
        }
    }
);

NewTaskList.Sort(); //new
TaskList.Clear(); //new
TaskList = NewTaskList.ToList(); //new
```

Or does anyone have any other ideas/suggestions/improvements?

Comment: Why `TaskList.Clear()`at the end? Seem redundant to me. Otherwise looks good. I'm guessing that you're making a new list (`ToList)`) because you're going to keep doing something with the `NewTaskist`? Otherwise, might as well assign it directly to the `TaskList` (I mean, it's sorted already).  Another thought would be to make `NewTaskList` a `ConcurrentBag<T>` to save using your own locks. But that would mean you'd need to `ToList()`it, assign it to `TaskList`, then do `TaskList.Sort()`... kinda ugly.

Comment: I won't be doing anything further with `NewTaskList`. I'm using the `ToList()` to make sure that when the method this code is in completes, the objects in `TaskList` don't fall by the wayside. `TaskList` is a class level variable so we need them to persist. I wasn't sure if they would. This way I know they will.

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental flaw in your stated goal: what does it actually _mean_ for the tasks to start in order, and why do you think you have to impose this goal? As Frank's answer points out, while you can guarantee that each task is dequeued in order (indeed, the queue itself enforces that!), you don't have enough control over the scheduling of each thread to ensure anything beyond that. A thread could dequeue a task and then immediately be pre-empted, causing some other thread to dequeue the next task and start work before the earlier thread made any progress. Is that okay with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Will this work?* - **No.** Maybe most of the time, but not if you really need it ordered.

There is an inherent problem with the statement "they do have to start in order". What do you mean with "start"? You probably have a race condition there. Consider this modification:

```
x =>
{
    TaskClass tc = null;
    if (cq.TryDequeue(out tc))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(0, 1000));
        TaskTypeManager ttm = new TaskTypeManager();
         ...
```

As you can see, the only thing happening in order is your items being dequeued - after that, parallelism kicks in and no order is guaranteed. You need some kind of synchronization into `ProcessTaskItem`, up to the point where you consider the task to be actually "started".

Comment: Sorry. After reading your response I can see how the "start" would confuse people. Let me see if I can clarify a bit. We need the items in the `TaskList` to be accessed in the order in which they are within the list. I thought the best way to do that is to use a `ConcurrentQueue` so regardless of which thread from the `Parallel.For` loop gets the next slice of runtime, it will only be able to access the next item in order from the queue. Hopefully ensuring the items are access sequentially as if we were running a single threaded for loop over the original list.

Answer (score 1):

> Note they do NOT have to complete in sequential order, just start in sequential.

In multithreading this doesn't make sense in general. The operating system can suspend any thread at any time for a duration of around 15 milliseconds ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3kWlV6)). So a thread that started before another thread, might be immediately suspended after executing just a couple of instructions, essentially before having a chance to do anything, while the second thread runs miles away. And you have no control over it.

In your case *I believe* that what you want is to serialize the assignment of the properties `Working` and `Started`. This is doable, but it requires an extra step. You must make the assignment while the `Parallel` loop *enumerates* the source, not inside the delegate that is invoked in parallel. The easiest way to do this is to expose the `taskList` as an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators). Iterators in C# are methods that contain `yield return` statements. Here is an example:

```
IEnumerable<TaskClass> Iterator()
{
    foreach (TaskClass tc in taskList)
    {
        tc.Working = true;
        tc.Started = DateTime.Now;
        yield return tc;
    }
}
```

Now you could pass this iterator directly to the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method, but this would be a mistake. The `Parallel.ForEach` employs [chunk partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl) by default, that needs to be disabled with the [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) option, so that the parallel loop requests the next item from the iterator immediately before it is ready to process it:

```
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(Iterator(),
    EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
```

And now we are cooking:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    partitioner,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DISystem.MaxConcurrentThreads },
    (TaskClass tc) =>
    {
        TaskTypeManager ttm = new TaskTypeManager();
        ttm.ProcessTaskItem(tc);
    }
);
```

The `Working` and `Started` properties will be assigned in enumeration order. The `Parallel.ForEach` synchronizes the enumeration of the source, so avoid doing anything heavy inside the iterator. Otherwise the synchronization may affect the performance of the whole operation.

Comment: A bit unrelated to what you wrote, but I'm curious about this part you wrote: `The operating system can suspend any thread at any time for a duration of around 15 milliseconds.` How does that 15ms differ from one PC to the next, across different OSes, CPU architectures etc? Is there a big variance, or?

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti I don't really know these details. The 15 msec is a number that I remember mentioned in a number of posts, but now I can't find any such post. I just ran [an experiment](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3kWlV6) on the dotnetfiddle.net server, and the results are: maximum sleeping duration around 40 msec, and average around 10 msec. That machine apparently runs on Unix, and has 4 cores.

Comment: Brilliant stuff Theo!