# Fastest way to add List<T> contents to ConcurrentQueue<T>

Tags: c#, concurrent-queue

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307695/parallel-for-items-in-a-list-by-using-concurrentqueue-will-this-work) and noticed the OP was iterating a list to queue up items into a ConcurrentQueue.

```
ConcurrentQueue<TaskClass> cq = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskClass>();
for (int x = 0; x < TaskList.Count; x++)
    cq.Enqueue(TaskList[x]);
```

Is this necessary?

Is there a way to either:

- Add a large number of objects to a ConcurrentQueue, or
- Simply convert/cast a typed List into a ConcurrentQueue

Answer (score 7):

You will note that `ConcurrentQueue<T>` provides a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267303(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` and copies its contents, like so:

```
ConcurrentQueue<TaskClass> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskClass>(TaskList);
```

Why would this be faster than enqueuing each item one-by-one? Because being a constructor it is not bound by the type's thread-safety guarantee and, therefore, can get away with adding items without taking out any locks (additionally, if you look at the source you will see that Microsoft deliberately bypass some `volatile` field reads and writes for perf reasons).

See [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs,50871c13ec8cfd35) for proof.

P.S. *Unless you're creating large concurrent queues in a tight loop you are unlikely to observe a noticeable difference in performance, but it's worth remembering that the copy constructor is there if you need it.*